# @uncheckedVariance in Kotlin?

Tags: scala, generics, kotlin, contravariance, subtyping

In his talk [Compilers are Databases](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxyyJyB_Ssc&t=27m23s), Martin Odersky presents an interesting variance corner case:

```
class Tree[-T] {
  def tpe: T @uncheckedVariance
  def withType(t: Type): Tree[Type]
}
```

`T` is defined to be contravariant, because it is useful to think of a typed tree (`Tree[Type]`) as a subtype of an untyped tree (`Tree[Nothing]`), but not the other way around.

Normally, the Scala compiler would complain about `T` appearing as the return type of the `tpe` method. That's why Martin shuts up the compiler with an `@uncheckedVariance` annotion.

Here is the example translated to Kotlin:

```
abstract class Tree<in T> {
    abstract fun tpe(): T
    abstract fun withType(t: Type): Tree<Type>
}
```

As expected, the Kotlin compiler complains about `T` appearing in an 'out' position.
Does Kotlin have something similar to `@uncheckedVariance`?
Or is there a better way to solve this particular problem?

Comment: You really want to just use `Tree[Unit]` for untyped trees. It prevents more bugs (compile-time vs runtime error) and doesn't require you to work around the type checker (hey that's funny isn't it). Odersky was just Oderskying here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kotlin has an `@UnsafeVariance` annotation which is an equivalent to `@uncheckedVariance` in scala:

```
abstract class Tree<in T> {
  abstract fun tpe(): @UnsafeVariance T
  abstract fun withType(t: Type): Tree<Type>
}
```

Comment: Interesting, `@unsafeVariance` appears to be [a relatively recent feature](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/10/kotlin-1-0-beta-candidate-is-out/). Thanks!